# Dart Dev Compiler: Error: Cannot find module 'dart_sdk'

Tags: dart

I am searching about Dart to Javascript and trying to do some node play but got stuck on this error:

```dart
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dart_sdk'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shina\Desenvolvimento\dart_projects\tests_dart\example\main.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

What I did:

I have a `main.dart` and run the following command on it:

`dartdevc --modules node -o main.js .\main.dart`

After that i just run: `node main.js`.

This is my `main.dart` file:

```dart
main() {
  print("Hello World!");
}
```

This is the main.js file generated by dartdevc:

```
'use strict';
const dart_sdk = require('dart_sdk');
const core = dart_sdk.core;
const dart = dart_sdk.dart;
const dartx = dart_sdk.dartx;
const main = Object.create(dart.library);
main.main = function() {
  core.print("Hello World!");
};
dart.trackLibraries("minimain", {
  "main.dart": main
}, {
}, null);
// Exports:
exports.minimain = main;

//# sourceMappingURL=minimain.js.map
```